# Polylang custom flags blurry on mobile, sharp on laptop

Tags: polylang

Polylang custom flags display perfect on laptop but blurry on mobile. If I shrink my window on laptop to mobile width they are still sharp. Can you please help with making them sharp on mobile devices?

I uploaded custom flags to Polylang using these steps https://polylang.pro/doc/can-i-use-my-own-flags-for-the-language-switcher/

Adjusted the size in Additional CSS (Customizer)

```
.lang-item img {
    height: 16px! important;
    width: auto! important;
     }
```

(Flags are .png 16x16px but they were still displaying too big without the CSS for some reason)

Thanks a lot!